# Systemd write stdout to a log file but keep in journal as well

Tags: debian, systemd, logs

Hi I have created a service in Debian 11 that basically runs a nodejs backend app. This is my service definition:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Opmet rest api

[Service]
ExecStart=node /media/data/opmet_rest_api/dist/main.js
Restart=always
User=root
# Note Debian/Ubuntu uses 'nogroup', RHEL/Fedora uses 'nobody'
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/media/data/opmet_rest_api/
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/opmet/opmet.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/opmet/opmet.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So far all the `stdout` output it is writing to `/var/log/opmet/opmet.log`
But my question is there any option to still writing to that file and  also to journal so I can see also the logs using `journalctl`.

Now when I run `journalctl -u opmet.service` I get only start and stop messages:

```
-- Journal begins at Mon 2023-03-13 12:08:51 UTC, ends at Tue 2023-10-17 18:21:25 UTC. --
oct 17 17:09:15 rectared09d systemd[1]: Started Opmet rest api.
oct 17 17:38:31 rectared09d systemd[1]: Stopping Opmet rest api...
oct 17 17:38:31 rectared09d systemd[1]: opmet.service: Succeeded.
oct 17 17:38:31 rectared09d systemd[1]: Stopped Opmet rest api.
oct 17 17:38:31 rectared09d systemd[1]: opmet.service: Consumed 4.470s CPU time.
oct 17 17:51:45 rectared09d systemd[1]: Started Opmet rest api.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do this with `StandardOutput` and `StandardError`,. It's better you use `rsyslog` / `syslog-ng` (which receive their log data from the journal) to store the output of your service in a file.